# Multivariate normal distribution moments

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, quantum-field-theory

I would like to evaluate the following higher order moments of a multivariate normal distribution in the case of mean $0$ and in the case of mean $\mu$:
\begin{equation}
E[X_i^{2 n}] \qquad E[(X_i^2 X_{i+1}^2)^n]
\end{equation}
In the $0$ mean case I understand from the Wick Theorem that we should have $E[X_i^{2 n}]= \frac{(2 n -1)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}E[X_i^{2}]^n$ but I cannot obtain the combinatorial factors of the other. In the non-central case I am quite lost.

Comment: Is $X_i$ independent of $X_{i+1}$?

Comment: The covariance matrix is known, i.e. $E[X_{i} X_{j}]=\sigma_{i j}$

Comment: @Ninja Warrior Hey, I was wondering why are you interested in this very problem? I am almost sure that one can express  expectations of products of an arbitrary number of random variables in a closed form.

Comment: Things like this come up pretty often when someone wants to solve a problem using perturbation theory in statistical field theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us take $n \ge 2$ and $(i,j)$ such that $1 \le i \le n$ and $1 \le j \le n$ and $i \neq j$. Then we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&E\left[ X_i^{2 n} X_j^{2 n} \right] = \\
&&
\int_{{\mathbb R}^n}  x_i^{2 n} x_j^{2 n} \cdot
\frac{\exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2} (\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})^{T} \cdot {\bf C}^{-1} \cdot (\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})\right]}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{n} \det({\bf C})}} d^n \vec{x} =\\
&&
\int_{{\mathbb R}^n}  (x_i+\mu_i)^{2 n} (x_j+\mu_j)^{2 n} \cdot
\frac{\exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2} (\vec{x})^{T} \cdot {\bf C}^{-1} \cdot (\vec{x})\right]}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{n} \det({\bf C})}} d^n \vec{x} =\\
&& \sum\limits_{p=0}^{2 n} \sum\limits_{q=0}^{2 n} \binom{2 n}{p} \binom{2 n}{q} \mu_i^{2n-p} \mu_j^{2n-q} \left. \frac{\partial ^p}{\partial t_i^p} \frac{\partial ^q}{\partial t_j^q} e^{\frac{1}{2} \vec{t}^{T} \cdot {\bf C} \cdot \vec{t}} \right|_{\vec{t}=\vec{0}}=\\
&& \sum\limits_{p=0}^{n} \sum\limits_{q=0}^{n} \binom{2 n}{2p} \binom{2 n}{2q} \mu_i^{2n-2p} \mu_j^{2n-2q} \left. \frac{\partial ^{2 p}}{\partial t_i^{2 p}} \frac{\partial ^{2 q}}{\partial t_j^{2 q}} e^{\frac{1}{2} \vec{t}^{T} \cdot {\bf C} \cdot \vec{t}} \right|_{\vec{t}=\vec{0}}=\\
&&\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n} \sum\limits_{q=0}^{n} \binom{2 n}{2p} \binom{2 n}{2q} \mu_i^{2n-2p} \mu_j^{2n-2q} \cdot \frac{1}{(p+q)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{p+q}} \cdot \left.\frac{\partial^{2 p}}{\partial t_i^{2 p}}
\frac{\partial^{2 q}}{\partial t_j^{2 q}} \left( \sum\limits_{\xi,\eta=1}^n {\bf C}_{\xi,\eta} t_\xi t_\eta\right)^{p+q}\right|_{\vec{t}=\vec{0}}=\\
&&\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n} \sum\limits_{q=0}^{n} \binom{2 n}{2p} \binom{2 n}{2q} \mu_i^{2n-2p} \mu_j^{2n-2q}  \cdot \frac{(2p)! (2q)!}{(p+q)!2^{p+q}} \cdot
\sum\limits_{\sigma \in \Pi(\underbrace{i,\cdots,i}_{2 p},\underbrace{j,\cdots j}_{2 q})} \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{p+q-1} C_{\sigma_\xi,\sigma_{\xi+1}}
\end{eqnarray}
In the second line from the top we wrote out the definition of the expectation value. In the third line we changed variables $x_\xi \leftarrow x_\xi-\mu_\xi$ for $\xi=1,\cdots,n$. In the fourth line we expanded the power terms in the integrand in a series and introduced the characteristic function of a zero-mean multivariate Gaussian. In the fifth line we took into consideration that the only non-zero terms will be even moments. In the sixth line we expanded the exponential in the characteristic function in a Taylor series and took into account the fact that the only non-vanishing expansion terms is the one with $m=p+q$ and finally in the seventh line we evaluated the derivatives by introducing a sum over permutations $\Pi$ of a sequence of length $2(p+q)$.
The following Mathematica code illustrates the step from the sixth to the seventh line:

```
In[2199]:= Clear[CC]; Clear[t];
n = RandomInteger[{2, 7}];
{i, j} = RandomSample[Range[1, n], 2];
{p, q} = RandomInteger[{0, n}, 2]; If[p < q, tmp = p; p = q; q = tmp;];
T1 = D[Sum[
      CC[xi, eta] t[xi] t[eta], {xi, 1, n}, {eta, 1, n}]^(p + q), {t[
      i], 2 p}, {t[j], 2 q}] /. t[i_] :> 0;
T2 = (2 p)! (2 q)! Total[
    Product[CC[#[[xi]], #[[xi + 1]]], {xi, 1, Length[#] - 1, 2}] & /@ 
     Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[i, 2 p], ConstantArray[j, 2 q]]]];
Simplify[T1 - T2]

{p, q}
T2 = FullSimplify[T2];
A = Table[
    Coefficient[T2, (CC[i, j] + CC[j, i]), (2 q - 2 l)], {l, 0, 
     q}]/(CC[i, i]^(p - q) Table[CC[i, i]^l CC[j, j]^l, {l, 0, q}]);
TT2 = CC[i, 
     i]^(p - q) Sum[(CC[i, j] + CC[j, i])^(2 q - 2 l) CC[i, i]^
      l CC[j, j]^l A[[1 + l]], {l, 0, q}];
Simplify[T2 - TT2]



A - (2 p)! (2 q)!  Table[ 
   Binomial[p + q, 2 q - l] Binomial[2 q - l, l], {l, 0, q}]

Out[2205]= 0

Out[2206]= {2, 0}

Out[2210]= 0

Out[2211]= {0}
```

Update: 
Let $p=0,\cdots,n$ and $i=1,\cdots,n$. Then the following identity below holds true:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left.\frac{\partial^{2 p}}{\partial t_i^{2 p}}
\left( \sum\limits_{\xi,\eta=1}^n {\bf C}_{\xi,\eta} t_\xi t_\eta\right)^{p}\right|_{\vec{t}=\vec{0}} = (2p)! {\bf C}_{i,i}^p
\end{eqnarray}

Now, let $p,q=0,\cdots,n$  and $i,j=1,\cdots,n$. Then  the following identity below holds true:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left.\frac{\partial^{2 p}}{\partial t_i^{2 p}}
\frac{\partial^{2 q}}{\partial t_j^{2 q}} \left( \sum\limits_{\xi,\eta=1}^n {\bf C}_{\xi,\eta} t_\xi t_\eta\right)^{p+q}\right|_{\vec{t}=\vec{0}} =
&&(2 p)!(2 q)!{\bf C}_{i,i}^{p-q} \sum\limits_{l=0}^q \left({\bf C}_{i,j}+{\bf C}_{j,i}\right)^{2q-2l} \cdot {\bf C}_{i,i}^l {\bf C}_{j,j}^l \cdot \binom{p+q}{2q-l} \binom{2 q-l}{l} 
\end{eqnarray}

Likewise let $p,q,r=0,\cdots,n$ and $i,j,k=1,\cdots,n$. Then the identity below holds true:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left.\frac{\partial^{2 p}}{\partial t_i^{2 p}}
\frac{\partial^{2 q}}{\partial t_j^{2 q}} 
\frac{\partial^{2 r}}{\partial t_k^{2 r}} 
\left( \sum\limits_{\xi,\eta=1}^n {\bf C}_{\xi,\eta} t_\xi t_\eta\right)^{p+q+r}\right|_{\vec{t}=\vec{0}} =\\
&&(2 p)!(2 q)!(2 r)!
\sum\limits_{l=0}^r \sum\limits_{l_1=0}^{2 q} \sum\limits_{l_2=0}^{l_1/2}
\binom{2r-l}{l} \binom{p+q+r}{2r-l} \binom{2r-2l}{2q-l_1} \binom{l_1-l_2}{l_2} \binom{p+q-r+l}{l_1-l_2} \cdot \\
&&
{\bf C}_{i,i}^{p+q-r+l-l_1+l_2}
{\bf C}_{j,j}^{l_2} {\bf C}_{k,k}^{l}
\left( {\bf C}_{i,j}+{\bf C}_{j,i}\right)^{l_1-2 l_2}
\left( {\bf C}_{i,k}+{\bf C}_{k,i} \right)^{2 r-2 q+l_1-2 l}
\left( {\bf C}_{j,k} + {\bf C}_{k,j} \right)^{2 q-l_1}
\end{eqnarray}

```
n = 8;
For[which = 1, which <= 100, which++,
  p = RandomInteger[{0, n}];
  i = RandomInteger[{1, n}];

  T1 = D[Sum[
       CC[xi, eta] t[xi] t[eta], {xi, 1, n}, {eta, 1, n}]^(p), {t[i], 
      2 p}] /. t[i_] :> 0;
  T2 = (2 p)! CC[i, i]^p;

  If[! (Simplify[T1 - T2] === 0), Break[]];
  If[Mod[which, 10] == 0, PrintTemporary[which];];
  ];
Print["All matches "];

All matches 

n = 8;
For[which = 1, which <= 100, which++,
  {p, q} = RandomInteger[{0, n}, 2];
  {i, j} = RandomSample[Range[1, n], 2];

  T1 = D[Sum[
       CC[xi, eta] t[xi] t[eta], {xi, 1, n}, {eta, 1, n}]^(p + q), {t[
       i], 2 p}, {t[j], 2 q}] /. t[i_] :> 0;
  T2 = (2 p)! (2 q)! CC[i, 
      i]^(p - q) Sum[(CC[i, j] + CC[j, i])^(2 q - 2 l) CC[i, i]^
       l CC[j, j]^l  Binomial[p + q, 2 q - l] Binomial[2 q - l, 
       l], {l, 0, q}];

  If[! (Simplify[T1 - T2] === 0), Break[]];
  If[Mod[which, 10] == 0, PrintTemporary[which];];
  ];
Print["All matches "];


All matches 

n = 5;
For[which = 1, which <= 100, which++,
  {p, q, r} = RandomInteger[{0, n}, 3];
  {i, j, k} = RandomSample[Range[1, n], 3];

  T1 = (D[
      Sum[CC[xi, eta] t[xi] t[eta], {xi, 1, n}, {eta, 1, n}]^(p + q + 
         r), {t[i], 2 p}, {t[j], 2 q}, {t[k], 2 r}] /. t[i_] :> 0);
  T2 = (2 p)! (2 q)! (2 r)! Sum[
     Binomial[2 r - l, l] Binomial[p + q + r, 2 r - l] Binomial[
       2 r - 2 l, 2 q - l1] Binomial[l1 - l2, l2] Binomial[
       p + q - r + l, l1 - l2] CC[i, i]^(p + q - r + l - l1 + l2)
      CC[j, j]^l2 CC[k, k]^
       l (CC[i, j] + CC[j, i])^(l1 - 2 l2) (CC[i, k] + 
         CC[k, i])^(2 r - 2 q + l1 - 2 l) (CC[j, k] + CC[k, j])^(2 q -
          l1)
     , {l, 0, r}, {l1, 0, 2 q}, {l2, 0, l1/2}];
  If[! (Simplify[T1 - T2] === 0), Break[]];
  If[Mod[which, 10] == 0, PrintTemporary[which];];
  ];
Print["All matches "];



All matches
```

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z$ be a standard normal r.v. and set $\sigma_i\equiv\sigma_{ii}$. If $\mu_i\ne 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}X_i^{2n}&=\mathsf{E}(\sigma_iZ+\mu_i)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} \sigma_i^{k}\mu_i^{2n-k}\mathsf{E}Z^k \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k} \sigma_i^{2k}\mu_i^{2(n-k)}(2k-1)!!
\end{align}
because $\mathsf{E}Z^{2k}=(2k-1)!!$. When $\mu_i=0$,
$$
\mathsf{E}X_i^{2n}=\mathsf{E}(\sigma_iZ)^{2n}=\sigma_i^{2n}\mathsf{E}Z^{2n}=\sigma_i^{2n}(2n-1)!!.
$$

---

For the expectation of cross-products let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be independent standard normal r.v.s. Then $(X_i,X_j)\overset{d}{=}(v_iZ_1,v_{ij}Z_1+v_j Z_2)+(\mu_i,\mu_j)$, where
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_i & 0 \\
v_{ij} & v_j
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sigma_i}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_i^2 & 0 \\
\sigma_{ij} & \sqrt{\sigma_i^2\sigma_j^2-\sigma_{ij}^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the Cholesky decomposition of $\operatorname{Var}([X_i, X_j]^{\top})$. Using the multinomial theorem (when $\mu_i\ne 0$, $\mu_j\ne 0$, and $\sigma_{ij}\ne 0$),
$$
\mathsf{E}[X_iX_j]^{2n}=\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_5=2n}\binom{2n}{k_1,\ldots,k_5}\prod_{l=1}^5 \alpha_l^{k_l}\times \mathsf{E}Z_1^{k_1+2k_2+k_3}\mathsf{E}Z_2^{k_1+k_4},
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha_1&=v_iv_j, \quad \alpha_2=v_iv_{ij}, \\
\alpha_3&=v_i\mu_j+v_{ij}\mu_i, \\
\alpha_4&=v_j\mu_i, \quad \alpha_5=\mu_i\mu_j.
\end{align}
$$
When $\mu_i=\mu_j=0$ and $\sigma_{ij}\ne 0$, 
$$
\mathsf{E}[X_iX_j]^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_1^{2k}\alpha_2^{2(n-k)}(2(2n-k))!!\,(2k-1)!!.
$$

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment, but) 
What's the significance of the index $i$ here? Are you looking at a stochastic process? Otherwise, can we simply consider the bivariate case? If so, let's denote $i$ by $1$ and $j$ by $2$.

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are correlated, we can represent $X_2$ as a linear combination of $X_1$ and some independent $Y$. In any case, moments of products of normal variables (and their powers) can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments), for example.

Comment: I would like to know a general form for the combinatorial coefficients of the  Isserlis’ theorem

Comment: It should be possible, but I don't think the formula will be pretty if the $\sigma_{ij}$ are arbitrary, since Isserlis' theorem calls for the product of all pairs of $i$ and $j$ in a specific configuration. If you have to do it, probably best to just write a program to expand out all the terms. If you use R, you may want to check this out: https://github.com/tshmak/WishartMoment